# SPOJ Fashion giving runtime error Python

Tags: python

Problem description is here :  http://www.spoj.pl/problems/FASHION/

Process : Took  two lists as input , sort them using the sort() method in Python and then print the sum

Code :

```
import sys,os
#Need to maximize the product of two lists 
def process(index,line):
    p=line.split(" ")
    #print 'Line after splitting',p
    for i in p:
        if(index==0):
            men.append(int(i))
        else:
            women.append(int(i))

global men
global women
men=[]
women=[]    
''' First, you enter number of times you want to compare . 
    Second, you enter number of men/women 
    Then, you enter the real data 
'''


n=int(raw_input()) #This is for number of shows
num = int(raw_input()) #This is number of men/women


for t in range(0,n): #Do this "n" times

    men = []
    women = []
    for i in range(0,2): #Now, enter  the men data first  and women next

        line=raw_input()
        process(i,line)
    p=0

    temp = []
    men.sort()
    women.sort()

    for i in range(0,num):
        p = p + men[i]  * women[i]
    print p
```

Problem : It keeps giving runtime error :(

Some cases I have run :

```
In [16]: %run /home/crazyabtliv/SPOJ/Fashion.py
2
3
1 1 1
2 3 4
9
4 5 6
0 9 8
94

In [14]: %run /home/crazyabtliv/SPOJ/Fashion.py
1
5
1 1 0 0 0
10 10 9 9 9
20
```

Thanks !

Comment: what the code of your [runtime error](http://hs.spoj.pl/embed/guide) is ?

Comment: why dont you try testing your code with the [test input SPOJ provides you in the question page ?](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/FASHION/). Do you get the same output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what SPOJ shows it expect:

```
Input:
2
2
1 1
3 2
3
2 3 2
1 3 2

Output:
5
15
```

However, trying to run your program produces:

```
2
2
1 1
3 2
5      <- that is the output for the first contest. should not output yet
3
2 3 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dasdsad.py", line 35, in <module>
    p = p + men[i]  * women[i]
IndexError: list index out of range

C:\Python26\programas\zz_so>
```

So you have to modify your code to keep your results in memory til the last input is entered. Then also you should move some code in order to take into account that `num` can be different between contests.

This has been modified to work as expected:

```
def process(index,line):
    p = line.split(" ")
    for i in p:
        if(index==0):
            men.append(int(i))
        else:
            women.append(int(i))

n = int(raw_input()) #This is for number of shows
results = []
for t in range(0, n): #Do this "n" times
    men = []
    women = []
    num = int(raw_input()) #This is number of men/women
    for i in range(0,2): #Now, enter  the men data first  and women next
        line=raw_input()
        process(i,line)

    p=0
    men.sort()
    women.sort()

    for i in range(0,num):
        p = p + men[i]  * women[i]
    results.append(p)

for item in results:
    print item
```

Still the code can be greatly simplified:

```
def process(line):
    return sorted([int(i) for i in line.split()])

n = int(raw_input())         #This is for number of shows
results = []
for t in range(n):           #Do this "n" times
    num = int(raw_input())   #This is number of men/women

    men = process(raw_input())
    women = process(raw_input())

    p = sum(m*w for m, w in zip(men, women))
    results.append(p)

for item in results:
    print item
```

**edit:** I optimized a bit the code with a sum(generator_expresion) instead of the for loop

Comment: Thanks ! For both the things.  The modified code has   taught me a lot :)  Will  write it better from next time !Thanks again

Comment: youre welcome. there are more things you could do if you look the code with attention. For example you can change ` p = 0
    for i in range(num):
        p = p + men[i]  * women[i]`  with `p = sum([m*w for m, w in zip(men, women)])`

Comment: @crazyaboutliv Last thing: if you are coding spoj and want to analyze and improve your running code with others opinions, probably you want to post your proposals in [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks !  Loads of thanks ! Will do so from now on. Right now fighting with Prime Generator :) will do soon

Comment: @crazyaboutliv Ops! wrong, It seems SPOJ people [beg not to give solutions before the question set series is finish](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5064/time-limit-exceeds-hs11divs-how-to-make-it-faster). Well, I recognize they are right.